# How to provide parameters to mssql-ssrs CreateSubscription in Node.js?

Tags: node.js, sql-server, soap, reporting-services

I'm writing a Node.js script to schedule reports using Microsoft ReportingService2010.CreateSubscription method:

```js
import {ReportService} from 'mssql-ssrs'

const rs = new ReportService()
await rs.start(
    'http://my-report-server/ReportServer',
    {
        username: 'xxxxxxxx',
        password: 'xxxxxxxx',
        domain: 'DEV'
    },
    {
        useRs2012: false
    },
    'ntlm'
)
const client = rs.getClient()

const Parameters = [
    {
        Name: 'report_request_id',
        Value: 100
    }
]

const args = {
    ItemPath: '/TEST/Reports/MyReportType',
    ExtensionSettings: {
        RENDER_FORMAT: 'PDF',
        FILENAME: 'my-test-report',
        FILEEXTN: true,
        PATH: '/Test/Reports/',
        WRITEMODE: 'Overwrite',
        AUTOCOPY: 'False'
    },
    Description: 'My test report',
    EventType: 'TimedSubscription ',
    MatchData: '<ScheduleDefinition>' +
        '   <StartDateTime>2003-02-24T09:00:00-08:00' +
        '   </StartDateTime>' +
        '   <WeeklyRecurrence>' +
        '      <WeeksInterval>1</WeeksInterval>' +
        '      <DaysOfWeek>' +
        '         <Monday>True</Monday>' +
        '      </DaysOfWeek>' +
        '   </WeeklyRecurrence>' +
        '</ScheduleDefinition>',
    Parameters: Parameters
}

console.log(client.CreateSubscription(args, function (err) {
    console.log(err.response.data)
}, null, null))
```

But I always get the following error:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <soap:Body>
    <soap:Fault>
      <faultcode>soap:Client</faultcode>
      <faultstring>This report requires a default or user-defined value for the report parameter report_request_id. To run or subscribe to this report, you must provide a parameter value. ---&gt; Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ReportParameterValueNotSetException: This report requires a default or user-defined value for the report parameter report_request_id. To run or subscribe to this report, you must provide a parameter value.</faultstring>
      <faultactor>http://my-report-server/ReportServer/ReportService2010.asmx</faultactor>
      <detail>
        <ErrorCode xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">rsReportParameterValueNotSet</ErrorCode>
        <HttpStatus xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">400</HttpStatus>
        <Message xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">This report requires a default or user-defined value for the report parameter report_request_id. To run or subscribe to this report, you must provide a parameter value.</Message>
        <HelpLink xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=20476&amp;EvtSrc=Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ErrorStrings&amp;EvtID=rsReportParameterValueNotSet&amp;ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server%20Reporting%20Services&amp;ProdVer=13.0.5026.0</HelpLink>
        <ProductName xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">Microsoft SQL Server Reporting Services</ProductName>
        <ProductVersion xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">13.0.5026.0</ProductVersion>
        <ProductLocaleId xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">127</ProductLocaleId>
        <OperatingSystem xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">OsIndependent</OperatingSystem>
        <CountryLocaleId xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">1033</CountryLocaleId>
        <MoreInformation xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices">
          <Source>Microsoft.ReportingServices.ProcessingCore</Source>
          <Message xmlns:msrs="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices" msrs:ErrorCode="rsReportParameterValueNotSet" msrs:HelpLink="https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=20476&amp;EvtSrc=Microsoft.ReportingServices.Diagnostics.Utilities.ErrorStrings&amp;EvtID=rsReportParameterValueNotSet&amp;ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server%20Reporting%20Services&amp;ProdVer=13.0.5026.0">This report requires a default or user-defined value for the report parameter report_request_id. To run or subscribe to this report, you must provide a parameter value.</Message>
        </MoreInformation>
        <Warnings xmlns="http://www.microsoft.com/sql/reportingservices"/>
      </detail>
    </soap:Fault>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

I also tried

```js
const Parameters = {
    report_request_id: 100
}
```

but got the same error.

If I run the following script:

```js
const args1 = {
    ItemPath: '/TEST/Reports/MyReportType',
    HistoryID: undefined,
    ForRendering: false,
    Values: undefined,
    Credentials: undefined
}

console.log(client.GetItemParameters(args1, function (err, result) {
    console.log(result.Parameters)
}, null, null))
```

The output will be

```js
{
  ItemParameter: [
    {
      Name: 'report_request_id',
      ParameterTypeName: 'Integer',
      Nullable: false,
      AllowBlank: false,
      MultiValue: false,
      QueryParameter: true,
      Prompt: 'pi_work_unit_report_request_id',
      PromptUser: true,
      ValidValuesQueryBased: false,
      DefaultValuesQueryBased: false,
      ParameterStateName: 'MissingValidValue'
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I provide this parameter when calling CreateSubscription method using mssql-sss?